# In $\triangle ABC$, point $E$ bisects $BC$ and point $D$ trisects $AB$. If $CD$ and $AE$ meet at $P$, determine $CP:PD$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

> In a triangle $ABC$, $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $D$ is a point on $AB$ such that $AD : DB = 2 : 1$. If $CD$ and $AE$ intersect at $P$, determine the ratio $CP : PD$.

How do I solve it using only section formula and basic coordinate geometry. Without using straight lines or vectors to simplify.

Edit: I have taken the co-ordinates of vertices as $( x_a , y_a )$ so on.

I have assumed that $\overleftrightarrow{AE}$ is divided in the ratio $\sigma$:1 by P
and $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is divided in the ratio $\lambda$:1 by P.

and I have got an equation for $x$ co-ordinate as
$$\frac{\lambda(x_a + 2x_b) +3x_c}{3(\lambda + 1)} = \frac{\sigma(x_b +x_c) + 2x_a}{2(\sigma+1)}$$

I dont know what has to be done next. The answer is $3:2$

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAFh.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What did you try? At least draw a rough figure.

Comment: @Harshavardhan Hajeri Help us to help you. Show please your attempts.

Comment: Hi, thank you @SarGe and Michael rozenberg . I have posted the image with what I have tried. Sorry, I was not able to use mathjax properly so everything is in image. I am stuck at the last step.

Comment: @HarshavardhanHajeri, are we allowed to use similar triangles? It becomes very easy by geometry.

Comment: @SarGe yes we can apply concepts related to triangles and trignometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Lets consider the $\triangle CDB$ which is cut by the line $AE$. According to Menelaus theorem:
$$\begin{align}\frac{BE}{EC}\cdot \frac{CP}{PD}\cdot \frac{DA}{AB}&=1\\
\frac{CP}{PD}&=\frac{EC}{BE}\cdot \frac{AB}{AD}\\
&=1\cdot\left(\frac{2x+x}{2x}\right)\\ &=\frac{3}{2}\end{align}$$

---

**Alternate Method:**

Draw a $DF$ parallel to $AE$. We have, by basic proportionality theorem in $\triangle BAE$.

$$\frac{AD}{BD}=\frac{FE}{BF}\implies \frac{2}{1}=\frac{FE}{BF}$$

$E$ is the midpoint of $BC$, so $EC=x+2x=3x$.

Similarly for $\triangle CDF$, $$\frac{CP}{PD}=\frac{EC}{FE}\implies\frac{CP}{PD}=\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If a triangle satisfies these conditions, the ratio $\frac{\overline{CP}}{\overline{PD}}$ will always be the same no matter what the triangle looks like.

So, to make the computing easier, you can just place $B$ at $(0,0)$, $A$ at $(0,3)$, $C$ at $(2,0)$, $D$ at $(0,1)$, and $E$ at $(1,0)$ for instance.

Now find the linear equations of $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AE}$, and then figure out the coordinates of $P$. At this point, you can solve this question with section formula.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I have not learnt linear equations yet. I have to solve it using section formula and coordinates.

Comment: @HarshavardhanHajeri I mean the formulas for those two lines.

Comment: I understood that, but this is in an exercise before discussing lines, so I have to do it without using formulae for lines, and only use co-ordinates, distance formula and section formula. At least that is what I think has to be done and we are still not taught about line equations or how to get a line equation from given points.

Comment: I see. In this case, since you have the coordinates of $C$, $P$, and $D$, you can use the distance formula to find $\overline{CP}$ and $\overline{PD}$.

Comment: No, I don't have the co-ordinates of $P$

Comment: Well, beats me. I don’t know how to solve this question in this way either.

Comment: Yeah, I too think it can't be done without using concepts of lines. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

In the diagram, mark the centroid "$G$" (say) on $AE$.
Now join $D$ and $G$. 
you will notice that $\triangle{PEC} \sim \triangle{PGD}.$

now,
$\frac{BE}{GD} = \frac{3}{2}$   ( using Thales Theorem in $\triangle{ADG}$ & $\triangle{ABE}$ ).

Thus in $\triangle{PEC}$ and $\triangle{PGD}$,

we get that $\frac{CP}{PD} = \frac{CE}{BD} = \frac{3}{2}$    ($\because$ CE=BE)

Comment: Thank you! for your help :-)